# Oracle to MS SQL Query Conversion - Connect By Prior & sys_connect_by_path

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

could any folk have a bash at recreating this Oracle Query Into MSSQL

```
select 
dtree.dataid, 
dtree.subtype, 
sys_connect_by_path( dtree2.name, ' : ') ||' : ' || dtree.name "Folder Path" 
from 
dtree, 
dtree dtree2 
where 
dtree.parentid = dtree2.dataid 
start with 
dtree.dataid = %1 
connect by prior 
dtree.dataid = dtree.parentid 
Order siblings by dtree.name asc
```

The query is for Open Text's Livelink ECM app... the DTREE table holds a parent & child relationship for every item, to date all I've managed to do is report the contents of a folder & subfolders using this: -

```
WITH DATAID AS (
SELECT DATAID
FROM DTREE
WHERE parentID = %1
), tree AS (
SELECT x.SubType, x.Name, x.ParentID, x.DATAID
FROM DTREE x
INNER JOIN DATAID ON x.DATAID = DATAID.DATAID
UNION ALL
SELECT y.SubType, y.Name, y.ParentID, y.DATAID
FROM DTREE y
INNER JOIN tree t ON y.ParentID = t.DATAID
)
SELECT ParentID, DATAID, Name, SubType
FROM tree
```

I need to construct the full item path...

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: As you're not losing the will to live just yet, could you show what you've tried and come up with so far? What are you running into? Looking at your query (but having no oracle knowledge) it will probably something with a `recursive cte`.

Comment: I am assuming he does not know how to reverse-engineer the ORACLE-only sys_connect_by_path() function.

Comment: The query is for Open Text's Livelink ECM app... the DTREE table holds a parent & child relationship for every item, to date all I've managed to do is report the contents of a folder & subfolders using this: - 
WITH dataID AS (
    SELECT dataID
    FROM DTREE
    WHERE parentID = %1
), tree AS (
    SELECT x.SubType, x.Name, x.ParentID, x.DATAID
    FROM DTREE x
    INNER JOIN dataID ON x.dataID = dataID.dataID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.SubType, y.Name, y.ParentID, y.DATAID
    FROM DTREE y
    INNER JOIN tree t ON y.ParentID = t.DATAID
)
SELECT ParentID, DATAID, Name, SubType
FROM tree

Comment: Go have a look at this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/824509/sys-connect-by-path-equivalent-in-sql

Comment: Ok, this is my first question on here.... Sorry that hasn't formatted well

Comment: The query would be easier to answer if you provided sample data, desired results, and set up a SQL Fiddle (using SQL Server) for the example.